# angular directive auth all the logic in the service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I should manage a directive for a login
form because of append a msg just in case
the credentials are wrong so I end up with:

### HTML

```
<form role="form" name="form" data-auth="" data-ng-submit="getAuth()" class="form-signin">  
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" data-ng-model="user.email" class="form-control">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" data-ng-model="user.password" class="form-control">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

### JS

```
.factory('Auth', function($http,$q,$window) {
        return {
            send : function(data){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.post('/user/auth',data)
                    .success(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.reject([]);
                    });
                return deferred.promise; 
            },
            authenticate:function(data){

            }
        }
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,Auth) {
            $scope.user = {};
     })
     .directive('auth',function($window,Auth) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                controller: function($scope,$element) {
                    $scope.getAuth = function(){
                        Auth.send($scope.user).then(
                            function(response){
                                if( (typeof response.data !== 'undefined') && (response.data === $scope.user.email)){
                                   $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/admin';
                                }
                            },
                            function(reject){
                                $('#invalid-login').remove();
                                $element.prepend('<p id="invalid-login" class="text-danger text-center">Invalid login</p>');
                            }
                        ); 

                    };
                }
            };
        });
```

I'd like to put all the logic in the service
but I don't find the way ^^

### EDIT

```
.factory('Auth', function($http,$q,$window) {
        return {
            send : function(data){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.post('/user/auth',data)
                    .success(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.reject([]);
                    });
                return deferred.promise; 
            },
            authenticate:function(data,callBackOnError){
                this.send(data).then(
                    function(response){
                        if( (typeof response.data !== 'undefined') && (response.data === data.email)){
                            $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/admin';
                        }
                    },
                    callBackOnError
                );
           }
        }
    })
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,Auth) {
        $scope.user = {};
     })
    .directive('auth',function($window,Auth) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function($scope,$element) {
                $scope.getAuth = function(){
                    Auth.authenticate(
                        $scope.user,
                        function(reject){
                            $('#invalid-login').remove();
                            $element.prepend('<p id="invalid-login" class="text-danger text-center">Invalid login</p>');
                        }
                    ); 
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

not so bad ^^

Comment: You can create one service for handling the ajax request and another for handling the business logic if thats what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML such that your call to getAuth has the user as parameter

```
<form role="form" name="form" data-auth="" data-ng-submit="getAuth(user)" class="form-signin">  
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" data-ng-model="user.email" class="form-control">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" data-ng-model="user.password" class="form-control">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Remember me
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
```

Change your service such that it includes the getAuth function:

```
.factory('Auth', function($http,$q,$window) {
    return {
        send : function(data){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/user/auth',data)
                .success(function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject([]);
                });
            return deferred.promise; 
        },
        authenticate:function(data){

        },
        getAuth: function(user){
            send(user).then(
                function(response){
                    if( (typeof response.data !== 'undefined') && (response.data === $scope.user.email)){
                        $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/admin';
                }
            },
            function(reject){
                $('#invalid-login').remove();
                $element.prepend('<p id="invalid-login" class="text-danger text-center">Invalid login</p>');
            }
        ); 

    }
}
})
```

And finally change the controller like that:

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,Auth) {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.getAuth = Auth.getAuth;
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice but $element is missing in the service and all in all I hate managing html in a service imo